Production web.config file encrypted by past developer, how can I decrypt it?
First off, I'm new to development, and even newer to asp.net vb webpages so please explain every possible detail like I'm 4.  I have this massive asp.net vb web form project file for the internal websites for the utility I work for, and all the pages were made by the developer I replaced who retired.  I have made a new webpage to go in the project but that page has some sql queries that pull data from a database that no other page has pulled from before.  This is simple to add the database in the web.config file on my dev pc and the page is functional.
The problem begins with updating the web.config file up in production.  First the production web.config file is encrypted which is fine because security, but my dev pc web.config file is in a different framework (4.8) then the production config file (4.6.1), so if I encrypt my config file using the following command in cmd prompt "aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "file location of the web.config file to be encrypted", and then swap out in production, it then breaks the webpages in production.
I'm unable to decrypt the production config file when I copy it to my dev pc, and I've read that you cannot encrypt a file on one pc and then decrypt on another.  So I then got access to the old developers dev pc and tried decrypting there and got the error "The RSA key container was not found".  So I'm wondering if there is a way to decrypt the web.config file another way?
The problem begins with updating the web.config file up in production.  First the production web.config file is encrypted which is fine because security, but my dev pc web.config file is in a different framework (4.8) then the production config file (4.6.1), so if I encrypt my config file using the following command in cmd prompt "aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "file location of the web.config file to be encrypted", and then swap out in production, it then breaks the webpages in production.
I'm unable to decrypt the production config file when I copy it to my dev pc, and I've read that you cannot encrypt a file on one pc and then decrypt on another.  So I then got access to the old developers dev pc and tried decrypting there and got the error "The RSA key container was not found".  So I'm wondering if there is a way to decrypt the web.config file another way?

Personally, I would reach out to the previous developer if possible. I'd also be more cautious mentioning you work for a utility in conjunction with asking about encryption concerns on a public platform, given the current increase of threat actors targeting utilities.

Source build should not have a encrypted web config. Often both standard web config, and then a release web config exits. This VERY much suggests that after you build the project (in release mode), then the standard web config will have transforms to swap out the developer database connections to the production database. Then the config file is to be encrypted. In MOST cases the copy of the site on the production server will NOT suffice for a source copy to rebuild that site. Hence the site on the production server can't be used anyway, You need the source code project used to build the site.

In other words, taking the resulting published project from the production server will not work, and can't be used in most cases (not even all source code will exist). Thus, the source code project is required for changes and re-deployment.  And as I stated, it is VERY rare that the source code project and build will have a encrypted web config file, as that is usually the VERY last step before deployment. And you failed to mention if this is a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site application. (this question is perhaps the first question - what type of project is this? - we need to know).

In other words, you can just add additonal pages to the production site, you need the Visual Studio source project used to "build" the site, and that includes compiling of source code which will be stripped out at publish time, and only the final compiled output of the source code is going to be placed on the web server. And to make ANY change to the site, a full re-build is required. You can't JUST copy new pages to the web site, a full re-compile + rebuild is required. So do you have both source code files (code behind files here), or just the aspx pages?

So, you are to re-build the site - if it works ok, then you use a publish to a local folder, and THEN you can publish to the production server, and run the command to encrypt the web config (in fact, it will encrypt the conneciton strings - not all of the web config file). So, what happens if you publish to production using your current build? It should work just fine, assuming there is a transform + release web config. If that works, then publish to production, and run the web config encrypt on that server, and you are good to go.
